# Web Scraper with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, web-scraping

I'm trying to do a scraping exercise with Selenium, but I'm having a few problems.

Here is my code:

```
package ScraperPakage;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import java.util.List;

public class ScraperClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create a new instance of Firefox Browser
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //Open the URL in firefox browser
        driver.get("http://www.budgettravel.ie");


         // Check the title of the page
         System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

         List<WebElement> titles = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.travelOfferList"));
         for (int j = 0; j < titles.size(); j++) {
         System.out.println(  "\t - " + titles.get(j).getText() ) ;
        }
     driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The code returns the list of offer holidays, but ends with a list of errors that I don't know how to resolve.

Here is the output:

```
JavaScript warning: resource://cck2/CCK2.jsm, line 998: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript warning: resource://cck2/Preferences.jsm, line 556: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
1472551987508   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 62410
JavaScript warning: https://normandy.cdn.mozilla.net/static/bundles/selfrepair-068962304d04a2173e88.94ed0f93a4f3.js, line 11002: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
Page title is: Cheap Holidays 2016/ 2017, Cheap Sun Holidays from Dublin, All Inclusive Sun Package Holidays from Ireland, Cheap Last Minute Holidays & Deals, All Inclusive Late Holiday Deals - Budget Travel
     - Last Minute Deals
Where
When
Nights
From

Costa Blanca
21 Sep
7
€185pp

[ ... REST OF THE LIST ...]

Costa Dorada
22 Oct
7
€146pp
[Child 14212] WARNING: pipe error: 232: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 487
[Child 14212] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2027
[NPAPI 13576] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2027
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700'
System info: host: 'xxxx', ip: 'xxxx', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, appBuildId=20160623154057, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, browserVersion=47.0.1, platformVersion=6.1, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=Firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=Windows_NT, device=desktop}]
Session ID: 3ad95378-01d1-4c6c-a3ce-24f992fb5289
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:670)
    [... OTHER LINES LIKE THE LINE JUST ABOVE ...]
```

Also, the are two windows opening with 'Plugin Container for Firefox has stopped working'

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: plugin-container.exe
  Application Version:  47.0.1.6018
  Application Timestamp:    576c9637
  Fault Module Name:    mozglue.dll
  Fault Module Version: 47.0.1.6018
  Fault Module Timestamp:   576c85ba
  Exception Code:   80000003
  Exception Offset: 0000f02b
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    6153
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the errors at the end and the windows opening at the end.

Thanks